# Is there a way to use uniq to compare only the first n characters?

Tags: linux, bash, uniq

According to the documentation,

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uuniq.htm

The command can be used to ignore the first n characters

Suppose I wish to have the following

```
03/08/2002,2,HUST,RICC,53.0,,2.3,J S BULLARD,,2,2,3/3,46.0,,,
03/08/2002,2,HUST,RICC,53.0,,WON,M J WALKER,,10,1,2/2,49.5,,,
```

Matched as identical based on the first 20 characters.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It seems you are not interested in characters >20. Maybe its enough to "simulate" `uniq -w` by `cut -c-20 YOURFILE | uniq`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My `uniq` manual (coreutils 8.5) says:

> ```
> -w, --check-chars=N
> compare no more than N characters in lines
> ```

This however isn't [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) (thus won't work on other Unixes).

Comment: FYI, the format for the **-w** switch is, for example: `uniq -w 37`